# pickling a matplotlib figure to reuse subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, pickle, subplot, axes

I'm attempting to take a script-generated figure, pickle it, and then load it later in a different scope to re-use some of the subplots in a new figure (by this I mean draw a new copy visually identical to the old). From the limited testing I've done, pickling and re-loading a figure object appears to be the most reliable way to re-use an entire figure, as it seems to restore the artist with all of the same settings, which is why I'm going with pickling over passing a figure object.

The problem is that when I try to use the axes individually, the new subplots are blank. I suspect that I'm missing something simple but obscure about how to command matplotlib to render the axes objects.

This is with Python 3.6.8, matplotlib 3.0.2. Suggestions are welcome.

```
#pickling & reusing figures

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

x = np.linspace(0, 10)
y = np.exp(x)
fig = plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.plot(x, 2*y)
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.plot(x,x)
plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.plot(x, 2*x)

subplots = fig.axes
plt.show()

with open('plots.obj', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(subplots, file)

plt.close(fig)

#simulation of new scope
with open('plots.obj', 'rb') as file:
    subplots2 = pickle.load(file)

plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(2,2,1)
subplots2[0]
ax2 = plt.subplot(2,2,2)
subplots2[1]
ax3 = plt.subplot(2,2,3)
subplots2[2]
ax4 = plt.subplot(2,2,4)
subplots2[3]

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to pickle the figure, not the axes.
- You shouldn't close the figure before pickling.

So in total,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

x = np.linspace(0, 10)
y = np.exp(x)
fig = plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.plot(x, 2*y)
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.plot(x,x)
plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.plot(x, 2*x)

with open('plots.obj', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(fig, file)

plt.show()
plt.close(fig)

#simulation of new scope
with open('plots.obj', 'rb') as file:
    fig2 = pickle.load(file)

# figure is now available as fig2

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This was actually something I'd already tested, but the entire figure is not the goal. The intent is to be able to extract the subplots and re-draw them individually as differently-arranged subplots in a new figure.

Comment: A subplot cannot live without a figure. But you can change the positions of the subplots inside `fig2` to your liking.

Comment: It seems like it might be useful to add a bit more context. The aim is to take several selected figures, and copy three of the four subplots of each figure into separate columns in a 3x4 subplot summary figure that's generated in a different scope and doesn't have access to the data. From what you're saying, I'm getting the impression that this isn't really feasible.

Comment: Oh, no, that's too brittle. One would need to loop through every single artist in each axes and change the transforms manually. The standard solution to this problem is to have four functions, one for each subplot of the original figure. Call those four functions with one of the axes of the original figure as input to get the first figure. Create a new figure, call three of those functions again with three axes of the new figure.

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to pass additional data back and forth between the scopes, but it sounds like I'll just have to. Thank you